# Windows Azure - Orphaned Disk. VHD and VM have already been removed

Tags: azure, disk, orphan

In the Azure management console, under Virtual Machines > Disks, I see 2 disks that both say they are attached to virtual machines.  However, those virtual machines have already been deleted.  Additionally, the disk blob vhds have already been deleted.  So now I'm left with 2 ghost disks that cannot be removed.  I'm unsure what the impact of leaving these is, and I want to remove them.  When I try to remove them with remove-azuredisk, I get an error.  I'm aware of the BreakLease.ps1 script that people have referenced to break a lease on a VHD in order to delete the VHD, but in my case there is no VHD.  The BreakLease.ps1 script appears to accept only URI as parameter, but I do not have a URI since this is not a VHD/blob.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get rid of these orphaned disk objects?

Thanks!

```
PS C:\> get-azuredisk | where-object {$_.diskname -like "*memb*"} | select diskname
VERBOSE: 2:35:33 PM - Begin Operation: Get-AzureDisk
VERBOSE: 2:35:34 PM - Completed Operation: Get-AzureDisk

DiskName
--------
coco2008memb3-coco2008memb3-0-201307022204430928
coco2008memb5-coco2008memb5-0-201307022204540471


PS C:\> get-azuredisk | where-object {$_.diskname -like "*memb*"} | remove-azuredisk
VERBOSE: 2:35:56 PM - Begin Operation: Get-AzureDisk
VERBOSE: 2:35:57 PM - Completed Operation: Get-AzureDisk
VERBOSE: 2:35:57 PM - Begin Operation: Remove-AzureDisk
remove-azuredisk : "An exception occurred when calling the ServiceManagement API. HTTP Status Code: 400. Service
Management Error Code: BadRequest. Message: A disk with name coco2008memb3-coco2008memb3-0-201307022204430928 is
currently in use by virtual machine coco2008memb3 running within hosted service coco2008memb3, deployment
coco2008memb3.. Operation Tracking ID: 8a8ab4956d5948ec9c23ec047259d086."
At line:1 char:61
+ get-azuredisk | where-object {$_.diskname -like "*memb*"} | remove-azuredisk
+                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzureDisk], ServiceManagementClientException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.IaaS.RemoveAzureDiskCommand

VERBOSE: 2:35:58 PM - Begin Operation: Remove-AzureDisk
remove-azuredisk : "An exception occurred when calling the ServiceManagement API. HTTP Status Code: 400. Service
Management Error Code: BadRequest. Message: A disk with name coco2008memb5-coco2008memb5-0-201307022204540471 is
currently in use by virtual machine coco2008memb5 running within hosted service coco2008memb5, deployment
coco2008memb5.. Operation Tracking ID: 69471c6e365e4dbca7ab714dfaddbe98."
At line:1 char:61
+ get-azuredisk | where-object {$_.diskname -like "*memb*"} | remove-azuredisk
+                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzureDisk], ServiceManagementClientException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.IaaS.RemoveAzureDiskCommand
```

Comment: The problem disappeared on its own after several hours without any additional interaction from me.  I simply logged back on later in the day and the two orphaned disks had disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

The problem disappeared on its own after several hours without any additional interaction from me. I simply logged back on later in the day and the two orphaned disks had disappeared!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IaaS Management Studio](http://iaas.ao-is.com/), you have a windows to see orphaned disks so you can delete them quickly. However, in some case I could not delete orphaned disks for several days. (Same problem by using powershell commands.